# How to combine select2 js and WebForms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, jquery-select2

I am trying to switch from Ext.net to select2 js.
I do not have clue how to combine scripts with controls.
Here is what I have tried so far.

I stared  new WebForms App, Installed select2 through NuGet and try to reproduce sample from [Project site](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Here is how looks like my aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="select2_test.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Select 2</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#e12").select2({ tags: ["red", "green", "blue"] });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { $("#e1").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
        <!--
            <input id="e12" /> 
            DO NOT WORK-->
        <!--
            <select id="e12">
            <option></option>
        </select> 
            DO NOT WORK-->
        <!--<section id="e12"></section>-->
        <!-- 
        <asp:TextBox ID="e13" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            DO NOT WORK-->

        <!-- This one only work as sample from web, others do not works-->
        <select id="e1">
            <option  value="0">Test 0</option>
            <option  value="1">Test 1</option>
            <option  value="3">Test 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What type of control I use when I want to apply JS on int ?
Is there any WebForms sample of using select2 js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
<select multiple id="e1">

    <option  value="0">Test 0</option>

    <option  value="1">Test 1</option>

    <option  value="3">Test 3</option>

</select>
```

Links of demo examples are given below :
    http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/
    http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/xra9k/

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with Select2. It has some side effects: it changes the ids of your controls. So if you use knockout.js and decided to apply select2 to your dropdown lists then you'll have a problem and the solution won't be nice.
Actually it's better to avoid using some third party's components or at least keep strict control of them.